# Android Studio incorrectly flagging arguments annotated with Snackbar.Duration

Tags: android, android-studio, annotations, android-snackbar

### Background

I wrote a wrapper around a default [`Snackbar.make`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#make(android.view.View,%20int,%20int)) method to apply custom styling to my `Snackbar` instances. The method signature of my custom wrapper is as follows:

```java
public static Snackbar makeCustom(
        @NonNull View view,
        @StringRes int resId,
        @Snackbar.Duration int duration)
```

where the `Snackbar.Duration` annotation is defined in `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.java` as follows:

```java
/**
 * @hide
 */
@IntDef({LENGTH_INDEFINITE, LENGTH_SHORT, LENGTH_LONG})
@IntRange(from = 1)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Duration {}
```

When I invoke `makeCustom` with the following arguments:

```java
makeCustom(
        activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
        messageResId,
        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

I see the following error in my IDE (Android Studio):

[image: A screenshot from Android Studio showing an error associated with the parameter Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT, which reads: "Value must be >= 1 (was 01)"]

I see no such error if I directly invoke `Snackbar.make`, which has the following signature:

```java
public static Snackbar make(
        @NonNull View view,
        @StringRes int resId,
        @Duration int duration) {
```

[image: A screenshot from Android Studio showing no error associated with the parameter Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT]

It would appear that when used in my own method signature, Android Studio fails to recognize that values satisfying *either* of the following constraints

```java
@IntDef({LENGTH_INDEFINITE, LENGTH_SHORT, LENGTH_LONG})
@IntRange(from = 1)
```

should be considered valid, instead expecting that values satisfy *both* of the above constraints simultaneously (which is impossible, since `LENGTH_INDEFINITE`, `LENGTH_SHORT` and `LENGTH_LONG` have values `-2`, `-1` and `0` respectively).

### Questions

- Am I applying the `Snackbar.Duration` annotation properly?
- If so:

  - Is the flagged error an Android Studio bug?
  - Is this weird behavior perhaps why the annotation is marked as hidden in the source code?

Comment: I have not played with creating these sorts of annotations. Since this is hidden, did you clone it and are using your own copy?

Comment: Actually, it dawns on me that `@hide` doesn't work in libraries. It would seem like you are using it properly, but it still might be worth an experiment to clone it and refer to your copy.

Comment: Cloning seems to be a suitable workaround; very odd! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I agree that it's odd. After all, all the annotations come from a library. Maybe the nested interface has something to do with it. That's the first time I recall seeing a validation annotation implemented that way.

Comment: This bug has been reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216372

Comment: @Weizhi awesome find, thanks!